# Targeting a specific occurence in a string and replacing it

Tags: replace, lua

I have a string with multiple `/` in it and I am trying to convert this string in to `LaTeX` code. Basically `(a)/(b)` becomes `\\dfrac{a}{b}`.

The difficulty is that (a) and/or (b) could contain other `/`.

To respect the parentheses balancing, I would like to replace the `/` from left to right, and replacing them accordingly to what it around. I made a try but I don't know how target a specific `/` and replace. using position and length parameters seems to be very complicated.

```
function ToFrac (s)
    while s:find ("/") ~= nil
    do

    -- Replace : \dfrac{}{}/() -> \dfrac{\dfrac...}{}
    if ( s:find ( '\\dfrac%b{}%b{}/%b()' , j ) ~= nil )
    then
    x,y,num,den = s:find( '(\\dfrac%b{}%b{})/(%b())' )
    den = den:gsub( '.(.+).' , '%1' )
    s = s:gsub( '(\\dfrac%b{}%b{})/(%b())',
                            "\\dfrac{"..num.."}{"..den.."}" , 1 )
    end

    print ('### -- ', s)

    -- Replace : ()/\dfrac{}{} -> \dfrac[}]{\dfrac...}
    if ( s:find ( '(%b()/\\dfrac%b{}%b{}' ) ~= nil )
    then
    x,y,num,den = s:find( '((%b())/(\\dfrac%b{}%b{})' )
    num = num:gsub( '.(.+).' , '%1' )
    s = s:gsub( '((%b())/()\\dfrac%b{}%b{})',
                            "\\dfrac{"..num.."}{"..den.."}" , 1 )
    end

    print ('### -- ', s)

    -- Replace : ()/() -> \dfrac{}{}
    if ( s:find ( '%b()/%b()' , 1 ) ~= nil )
    then
        x,y,num,den = s:find( '(%b())/(%b())' )
        num = num:gsub( '.(.+).' , '%1' )
        den = den:gsub( '.(.+).' , '%1' )
        s = s:gsub( '(%b())/(%b())',
                        "\\dfrac{"..num.."}{"..den.."}" , 1 )
        Done = true
    end

    print ('### -- ', s)

    end -- while

    return (s)

end

s = "((a)/(b))/(c)"
print (s, ToFrac(s))

s = "(a)/((b)/(c))"
print (s, ToFrac(s))

s = "(a)/(b)/(c)/(d))"
print (s, ToFrac(s))

s = "((a)/(b))/((c)/(d))"
print (s, ToFrac(s))
```

Comment: The nested requirement suggests patterns/regex is a bad idea. A recursive descent parser would be simpler. I was going to write you an example, but your spec is insufficient. You need to show examples of expected output for various inputs, including inputs with nesting, worse case `/` usage, etc. For instance, what should `((testing)/(a/b/c))/(1,(zip/zap///x),3)` produce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amended version of rpattiso's idea:

```
function to_frac(expr)
  local t
  return expr == '' and '' or (expr..'()'):gsub('(.-)(%b())',
    function(prefix, subexpr)
      local replace_with = ''
      if not prefix:find'^%s*/%s*$' then
        t, replace_with = {}, (not t and ''
          or t[2] and '\\dfrac{'..t[1]..'}{'..t[2]..'}'
          or '('..t[1]..')')..prefix
      elseif t[2] then
        t = {'\\dfrac{'..t[1]..'}{'..t[2]..'}'}
      end
      table.insert(t, to_frac(subexpr:sub(2,-2)))
      return replace_with
    end
  )
end

print(to_frac' (a )/((b) / (c))')   --> \dfrac{a }{\dfrac{b}{c}}
print(to_frac'((a)/((b)/(c)))/(e)') --> \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{b}{c}}}{e}
print(to_frac'(a)/(b)/(c)/(d)')     --> \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}
```

Comment: I must keep fractions, not convert them to multiplications. It's the sudent's job ;-)

Comment: I try to understand and lurn from your code. Could you please comment a little lines 3 and 4 ? And according to a boolean `Parentheses` I'd like to keep de parenthesis on numbers (work with relatives : (+3) and (-1.5). I tried to work on line 13, without success, because I don't understand exactly what is done. Thank you.

Comment: I've found the solution putting back the `()` at the end if needed. In finally understand how it works. Thank you I've lurned a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The 'replace' argument of `string.gsub` can be a function.
Using that function, you can apply the substitution recursively to the numerator and denominator and build the result that way. `string.sub` can be used to remove the parentheses from the numerator and denominator.

```
function to_frac(expr)
     return (expr:gsub('%s*(%b())%s*/%s*(%b())%s*',
         function(num, denom)
             return '\\dfrac{'..to_frac(num:sub(2,-2))..'}{'
                              ..to_frac(denom:sub(2,-2))..'}'
         end))
end


expr = ' (a )/((b) / (c))' -- \dfrac{a }{\dfrac{b}{c}}

print(to_frac(expr))


expr = '((a)/((b)/(c)))/(e)' -->\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{b}{c}}}{e}
print(to_frac(expr))
```

If you want to go beyond using parentheses for delimiting arguments and obey precedence rules, then look into LPeg.

Comment: Nice!  And what about `(a)/(b)/(c)/(d)` ?  It equals to `a/(bcd)`, not `(a/b)/(c/d)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it's limited to using `/` in the form (a)/(b). I'd say LPeg is the answer for beyond that.

Comment: Thank you, I learned how to use a function in gsub. Your pattern doesn't deal with string from it involves a `dfrac` in remplacement. I can't use `LPeg` beacause it's not standart in `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: @Tarass another option is to build the string using custom Lua objects and metamethods instead of parsing (like  sympy) `x, y = var('x y'); tostring(x / y * 3)` which would output LaTeX. This way you can extend it use other operators (like exponentiation) and the precedence rules are taken care of by Lua.